# Length between two circles intersection area?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

How do I know the (smallest) length of the intersection area between two circles of different sizes? We know both circles radii and the overlapping area.

[image]

https://www.lucidchart.com/publicSegments/view/55869c81-e0b0-43ee-bedb-51030a004e1f/image.png

Comment: What is the *length* of an *area*?

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far? For example, have you worked on this "backwards" and come up with an expression for the overlapping area given the radii and the "length of intersection"? You could try to invert that expression. Please show us that you have done significant work of your own: this is not a homework-answering site.

Comment: how was the area calculated?

Comment: do you know how far apart the centres are?